# How to output specific information from a powershell command?

Tags: powershell, object, output, piping

So I've been playing around with Powershell recently, trying some things with a basic command `net user $username`. As an example `net user administrator` [produces an output that you can see at the bottom of this page.](https://www.lifewire.com/net-user-command-2618097)

My question is: How do I output specific elements of this?

I'm aware of pipes and have been trying to use them but I think I'm missing something as it never comes out right. Lets say, for example, I just want `user name`, `full name`, `password expires` and `last logon` to be shown as an output. What command do I use after the pipe to get this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`net.exe` is not a PowerShell cmdlet. Therefore getting information out it is processing the output of the executable as a string.

For example, retrieving the user name:

```
$netoutput = net user administrator
#User name is on the first line, separated by spaces, the actual username is last word
$netoutput[1].Split(" ")[-1]
```

If you are using Win10 1607 or newer, you could retrieve this information with the `Get-LocalUser` cmdlet

```
Get-LocalUser administrator | Select-Object Name,FullName,PasswordExpires,LastLogon
```